# Wordpress - the_excerpt() not working

Tags: youtube, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have been working on converting an html page to wordpress. I have successfully converted the elements. But my slider has an embedded youtube video. the below code if from my html theme

```
<iframe width="420" height="345"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>
```

I want to get this youtube link as a post.

**What I have tried**

```
<?php query_posts('cat=3','&posts_per_page=1'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <iframe width="420" height="345"
    src="<? the_excerpt(); ?>">
    </iframe>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

**What happened?**

I noted that my RAM usage increased rapidly, and keeps on doing the same, and I never got the video.

What is the cause of this? Have I done something wrong? Is there any other alternate solution to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<? echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>` in place of `<? the_excerpt(); ?>` as `the_excerpt()` prints the excerpt wrapped in `<p>` tag on the screen while `get_the_excerpt()` returns it without a `<p>` tag